# Is there any command to merge dataframes with different values in a specific column?

Tags: r

Having two dataframes with the same key id column:

```
dfnames1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), name1 = c("Helen", "Von", "Erik", "Brook", "Adel"), gender = c("F", "Neutral", "M", "Neutral", "F"))
dfnames2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), name2 = c("Helen", "Von", "Erik", "Brook", "Adel"), gender2 = c("Neutral", "M", "M", "Uni", "M"))
```

How is it possible to merge them into one data frame and for gender column check if it is "Neutral" label in one of the two dataframe and has another of the values of "F", "M" or "Uni" keep this label, if it is Neutral in both dataframes keep as it is and if the is a case of "F" and "M" or vice versus keep it as FM or MF.

Example of expected output:

```
dfnames <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), name = c("Helen", "Von", "Erik", "Brook", "Adel"), gender = c("F", "M", "M", "M", "FM"))
```

Comment: According to your conditions I think Brook should be `Uni`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the inputs shown in the Note at the end, create a state matrix (actually a data frame here) and use it to set `gender`

```
library(dplyr)

Lines <- "        M   F Neutral Uni  
          M       M  MF M       M  
          F       MF F  F       F  
          Neutral M  F  Neutral Uni
          Uni     M  F  Uni     Uni"
State <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)

left_join(dfnames1, dfnames2, by = "id") %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(gender = State[gender, gender2]) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(id, gender)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
     id gender
  <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 F     
2     2 M     
3     3 M     
4     4 Uni   
5     5 MF
```

### Note

```
dfnames1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), name1 = c("Helen", "Von", 
"Erik", "Brook", "Adel"), gender = c("F", "Neutral", "M", "Neutral", 
"F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

dfnames2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), name2 = c("Helen", "Von", 
"Erik", "Brook", "Adel"), gender2 = c("Neutral", "M", "M", "Uni", 
"M")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you! In the lines it is possible to insert the FM option as well?

Comment: You can change the state matrix to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to change to add the MF version adding rows with the opposite but it refers it as duplicate row. Please could you give me one explanation how it works?

Comment: The row names are the possible gender values and the column names are the possible gender2 values.  The cell values are the desired result when that combination of gender/gender2 is found.  It doesn't make sense to have duplicate row names or column names so whatever you did needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Using dplyr we could it this way:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(dfnames1, dfnames2) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("gender"), ~ifelse(. == "Neutral", NA_character_, .)),
         x = coalesce(gender, gender2),
         x = ifelse(!is.na(gender2) & x != gender2, paste0(x, gender2), x)) %>% 
  select(id, name=name1, gender = x)
```

```
Joining, by = "id"
  id  name gender
1  1 Helen      F
2  2   Von      M
3  3  Erik      M
4  4 Brook    Uni
5  5  Adel     FM
```